# Using Sticky Kit jQuery plugin, but can't figure out how to use the 'recalc' option?

Tags: jquery, css, fixed, sticky

I have some Collapsible Panel in right side that I want to fix them when scroll. when one collapsible panel get class 'in' the sticky kit should recalculate. but I don't know how to use recalc in my code. my code is below:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
    $(".filter").stick_in_parent()
}, 600)
```

I use http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/#reference for fixed sidebar

Comment: Please share ur code or provide a demo.

Comment: I use this http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/#reference